# Why query shows result, however most of parameter values are wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I would like to ask very humbly that my two queries are showing different results. In both queries I have pass two wrong values (city id and state it), but still query shows return a row when I am executing. Following is the query which shows row and I am expecting it should not

```
select * from `companies` where `city_id` = 3 and `state_id` = 4 and 
`company_name` LIKE '%en%' 
or `company_email` LIKE '%en%'
or `company_profile` LIKE '%en%'
order by `company_name` asc
```

And the following query does not show any row, and it is expected result because of passing wrong values

```
select * from `companies` where `city_id` = 3 and `state_id` = 4 and 
`company_name` LIKE '%en%' 
or `company_email` LIKE '%en%'
order by `company_name` asc
```

The only difference in both of queries is like clause

```
or `company_email` LIKE '%en%'
```

Can someone kindly guide me that why it is happening. I would like to appreciate. I am so sorry if I made any mistake.

Comment: guess you wanted something like this

select * from `companies` where `city_id` = 3 and `state_id` = 4 and 
(`company_name` LIKE '%en%' 
or `company_email` LIKE '%en%'
or `company_profile` LIKE '%en%')
order by `company_name` asc

Comment: You need parentheses around the OR part.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks a lot, can you kindly give me an example

Comment: Look at @ViktarPryshchepa's comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you mix `and` and `or` suggests you aren't fully aware of their [precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html). `AND` has higher precedence than `OR` thus your queries are equivalent to these:

```
where (
    `city_id` = 3
    and `state_id` = 4
    and `company_name` LIKE '%en%' 
)
or `company_email` LIKE '%en%'
or `company_profile` LIKE '%en%'
```

```
where (
    `city_id` = 3
    and `state_id` = 4
    and `company_name` LIKE '%en%' 
)
or `company_email` LIKE '%en%'
```

I presume your only match is due to `company_profile`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working. I would like to appreciate for sharing knowledge with me.

Answer (score 0):

Let me rephrase myself. As it was pointed out AND have a bigger precedence to OR, but, if the AND conditions did not return results, and any of the OR condition return, the OR will take over everything else you wrote.

As of, if the AND conditions you set return results, the OR conditions will be ignored.

For it to work like it (apparently) should, you would need to do this:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    `companies` 
where 
    `city_id` = 3 
and 
    `state_id` = 4 
and (
    `company_name` LIKE '%en%' 
    or `company_email` LIKE '%en%'
    or `company_profile` LIKE '%en%'
)
order by `company_name` asc
```

Comment: Sorry, it's the other way round: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html

Comment: Damn :D

I thought something and wrote something else.